# Disabling Aria INSERT log in MariaDB

Tags: mariadb, storage-engine, mariadb-10.5

When I bulk `INSERT` into an `Aria` table, it creates a copy of the `INSERT` in a series of log files (aria_log.%). It can lead to full disk and crash of MySQL.

As I understand, Aria keeps a redo log for `TRANSACTIONAL=1` only, and the default behaviour is `TRANSACTIONAL=0`. I also created a table specifically with `TRANSACTIONAL=0`, but the same behaviour.

I use Aria for a sort of backup, as it is faster than InnoDB on HDD, and do not need transactional/crash-safe behaviour.

How can I disable Aria logging and only writing into the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After lots of experimentations, I found out that the problem was not `TRANSACTIONAL`, but `PAGE_CHECKSUM`.

The default behaviour of Aria is `PAGE_CHECKSUM=1` for which Aria keeps a copy of the inserting rows in the log file.

You need `PAGE_CHECKSUM=0` for disabling large log files.

Comment: Well discovered. Do you consider this something that needs improvements or is impacting? [Bug/feature request welcome](https://jira.mariadb.org).

Answer (score 1):

Many of the system tables in the `information_schema`, `mysql` and `sys` databases use the Aria storage engine, and some of these have `transactional=1`. So even if you create a table with `transactional=0`, there will still be other tables with `transactional=1`.

Also, are you sure you have no Aria tables of your own with `transactional=1`? Here's a quick query to find all Aria tables (including system tables) with `transactional=1`:

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, ENGINE, CREATE_OPTIONS
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
WHERE ENGINE = 'Aria' AND 
  CREATE_OPTIONS LIKE '%transactional=1%';
```

Comment: that query returns empty on my system. Anyhow, when I `INSERT` into a newly created table with `TRANSACTIONAL=0`, why does Aria keep a copy of the inserting data in log files. `TRANSACTIONAL` is set at table level, not system level.

Comment: @Googlebot yes, I know it's set at table level. Are you literally getting an empty result set from that query - not even any system tables? Which MariaDB version is this? Have you verified that the aria_log.% file grows when you insert into your transactional=0 Aria table?