# Is it possible to temporarily disable TRANSACTIONAL in an ARIA table?

Tags: mariadb

When I try to quickly insert many rows to restore some data, large aria_log.% files are created and the operation seems very slow.

I can do

```
ALTER TABLE table TRANSACTIONAL=0;
```

and then restore it back

```
ALTER TABLE table TRANSACTIONAL=1;
```

But this is a very slow conversion process.

LOCK/UNLOCK TABLES also doesn't speed up the process.

How to run INSERT without logging into aria_log.% ?

Comment: See [Disabling Aria INSERT log in MariaDB](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/302601/disabling-aria-insert-log-in-mariadb) if it helps